# Prove $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^x$, where $x$ is any positive real number and $n$ is any positive integer.

Tags: inequality

I am having trouble with my homework problem, it says:

> Suppose that $n$ is a positive integer and that $x > 0$. Show that
>   $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^x.$$

I have proved the base case, but I am unsure how to proceed with the induction step. The question continues:

> and, if $x < n$, then
>   $$e^x < \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}$$
>   Also, by choosing a suitable $n$, deduce that $2.5 < e < 2.99$.

I would like a hint to help me along if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Which definition of $e$ are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

Just see this for $x>0$

> $$e^{n\ln(1+x/n)}  < e^{n(x/n)} =e^x$$

since $\ln(1+t)<t$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one,
$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^x
\iff
1+\frac{x}{n} < e^{x/n}
$
and this follows from
$e^x \ge 1+x
$
with equality only if
$x = 0$.

For the second one,
$e^x < \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}
\iff
e^{x/n} < \frac1{1-\frac{x}{n}}
$
and this follows from
$e^x <
\frac1{1-x}
$
if $0 < x < 1$.
This, in turn, follows from
$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$
and
$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$
if $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: For an arguably more symmetric approach, $e^x<\frac{1}{1-x}$ can also be established by noting its equivalence to $1-x<e^{-x}$, which is simply $e^x>1+x$ with $x\to-x$.

Answer (score 0):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) implies that
$$
\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
$$
is increasing in $n$ for $x\gt-n$. This implies that for $x\gt0$
$$
\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\le e^x
$$
and for $n\gt x\gt0$
$$
\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n\le e^{-x}
$$
and so
$$
\left(1-\frac xn\right)^{-n}\ge e^x
$$